# Simplifying Repeated Infinite Summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

While reading a solution to a math olympiad problem, I came across a repeated, infinite summation I've never seen before. The author somehow simplifies the summation to a numerical result, but doesn't elucidate how the simplification was made. It may involve a formula that I don't know of, but I am not sure. [image] Could someone enlighten me with an explanation?

[Here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2018_AMC_12A_Problems/Problem_19) is a link to the full problem and solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(a)$, $g(b)$, and $h(c)$ are *any* functions, then a triple sum can be factored:
$$
\sum_{a=0}^A \sum_{b=0}^B \sum_{c=0}^C f(a)g(b)h(c) = \bigg( \sum_{a=0}^A f(a)\bigg) \bigg( \sum_{b=0}^B g(b)\bigg) \bigg( \sum_{c=0}^C h(c) \bigg).
$$
(This is just a souped-up version of $wy+wz+xy+xz=(w+x)(y+z)$.)

Under suitable conditions (which include $f$, $g$, and $h$ all being nonnegative), we can take the limit as $A,B,C\to\infty$ and obtain
$$
\sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{b=0}^\infty \sum_{c=0}^\infty  f(a)g(b)h(c) = \bigg( \sum_{a=0}^\infty f(a)\bigg) \bigg( \sum_{b=0}^\infty g(b)\bigg) \bigg( \sum_{c=0}^\infty h(c) \bigg).
$$
This is what the author used, with $f(a)=1/2^a$ and so on.

Comment: Whoops, I should've caught that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint

The left hand side

$$=\sum_{a=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac12\right)^a\sum_{b=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac13\right)^b\sum_{c=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac15\right)^c$$

$$=\sum_{a=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac12\right)^a\sum_{b=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac13\right)^b\dfrac1{1-\dfrac15}$$